# Reimaging iBook G3 with Panther from Windows machine?

Tags: macos, mac, ibook

I have a working iBook G3 that I want to wipe the hard drive and install OS X Panther on. If I remember correctly it is currently running OS 8.6. Except the only other machine I have to create discs to image it is a Windows machine.

I have copies of the OS discs but they're in toast format. I heard that renaming them to a .bin format should work, but when I powered on the machine holding the "c" key with the disc in, it booted to desktop.

Is there a way that I can either boot from a flash drive with the disc information on it, or do I need to use a different format for the discs?

Comment: https://pureinfotech.com/make-bootable-usb-mac-os-x-windows/ should also work for obsolete releases.

Comment: A G3 won't boot from USB. You'll need a method to get that toast file onto a CD. Finding a friend with a Mac & CD burner is going to be the easiest way. OS X can read toast files natively & convert to iso.